# Div not hiding in tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built a site that uses Javascript to hide certain divs and display them only when the tab is opened.

My problem is that one of my divs appear in all the tabs and I don't know what the problem is.

Annoying DIV:

```
<div class="tabContent" id="history">
 <h2>History</h2>
 <div>

 </div>
```

JavaScript code for showing divs:

```
 function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
  // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }

  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `getHash` ? `contentDivs` ? `tabLinks` ? We can take a *guess* as to what those are, but you should try to provide a more concise example so we definitely know. If `contentDivs` is a [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you should avoid using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing elements of setting with *display:none;* only work by *display:none;* is setting with inline.

So you cannot use class for hiding/showing elements.

Available codes below.

```
<div class="tabContent" id="history" style="display:none;">
    <h2>History</h2>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
  // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].style.display = '';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
}
```